# SQL - Ordering by pairs of rows

Tags: sql, mysql

Can someone help me come up with a SQL query to do the following

Order a table by individual pairs of rows, where the pairs are consecutive rows based on timestamp. Then order all of these pairs by the average of an attribute of both rows in given pair. Select the first pair / two rows.

thanks. ive been puzzling over it for while and am not sure where to start.

Example:

```
[Timestamp] [Views]
1           23
2           17
3           30
4           5
5           47
6           15
```

Order pairs(timestamp) by SUM(views) ASC

```
[Timestamp] [Views] [(sum)]
3           30       35
4           5
1           23       40
2           17
5           47       62
6           15
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and sample result.

Comment: Are there any gaps in the timestamp field? or will it always* have every number from the min to the max?

Comment: yes - assume the timestamp field always has a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `timestamp` field is always in a sequence and *has no gaps*, this query should work:

```
SELECT t.Timestamp, t.Views,
  IF(t.Timestamp % 2, t.Views + tPair.Views, NULL) As Sum
FROM tableName t JOIN tableName tPair
  ON IF(t.Timestamp % 2, t.Timestamp + 1, t.Timestamp - 1)  = tPair.Timestamp
ORDER BY t.Views + tPair.Views, t.Timestamp
```

Otherwise, you need to copy the results to a temp table with a autoincrement field to generate the full sequence.

Comment: the actual use of this doesn't involve a timestamp field that is always in a sequence, so I'll try using a temporary table

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a huge number of rows, you can write a stored procedure that will walk through the underlying dataset, store the data for each sequential pair of rows in memory variables, perform the averaging operation, write the average to the variables, and then write the variables to a pair of rows in a temporary memory-only table.  Then, rinse and repeat...

That temporary table can then be queried and sorted in any order you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first attempt, and i'm sure it could be improved:

```
with nosort as (
    select time, views, sumviews
    from #temp t1
    left outer join
        (select min(time) as mintime, sum(views) as sumviews
       from #temp
       group by (time-1)/2) t2 on t2.mintime=t1.time
    where sumviews is not null
)
select t1.time, t1.views, t2.sumviews from #temp t1
join nosort t2 on t1.time=t2.time or t1.time=t2.time+1
order by sumviews
```